# Passing parameters to PostGIS SQL queries in Python: weird behaviour

Tags: python, postgis, sql

The following code always goes to the except section and I do not understand why..Any help would be much appreciated.

```
l = None
c = conn.cursor()
try:
  s = "SELECT ST_NPoints(ST_GeomFromText(%s))"
  d = (line,)
  c.execute(s,d)
  l = c.fetchall()
except:
  print "could not get the line vertices"

print line 

MULTILINESTRING((-3.16420835153456 55.9269166007097,-3.164222 55.926918),
(-3.1642070167833 55.9269296196706,-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904),
(-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904,-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897),
(-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897,-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802),
(-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802,-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886),
(-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886,-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667),
(-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667,-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093))
```

If I execute this in psql, it works fine. I also have the impression that I am following documentation perfectly regardging passign parameters to sql queries etc. When I call the function, I pass the argument as a string like this `'MULTILINESTRING((-3.164....565148822 55.9266503211093))'`

Comment: Have you tried to run the query with the `MULTILINESTRING` hard-coded? That will eliminate any funky parameter formatting that `execute()` might be doing.

Comment: Hi, yes I tried hard coding it and still does not work...

Comment: Have you tried removing the comma after line as in d=(line) ?

Comment: Yeap, I have excausted coding alternatives based on this document http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters..

Comment: I can't reproduce your example with psycopg2 version 2.4.2 on a postgres 9.0 DB with PostGIS 1.5. Can you run basic, non-PostGIS queries on the same connection?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post the exception so I don't know what is wrong with your query. But this should always work: (assuming that your projection is `WGS84` or in other words the SRID of your data is `4326`)

```
SELECT ST_NPoints(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;MULTILINESTRING((-3.16420835153456 55.9269166007097,-3.164222 55.926918),
(-3.1642070167833 55.9269296196706,-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904),
(-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904,-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897),
(-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897,-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802),
(-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802,-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886),
(-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886,-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667),
(-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667,-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093))'));
```

or in python:

```
l = None
c = conn.cursor()
try:
  s = "SELECT ST_NPoints(ST_GeomFromEWKT(%s))"
  d = ("SRID=4326;"+line,)
  c.execute(s,d)
  l = c.fetchall()
except Except, ex: # catch the exception so you can know what happened
  print "Error: ",str(ex)
```